# Project on slope, rates of change, and instantaneous rates of change

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I was wondering if someone could look over my work and tell me if I am doing this correctly. Also, I need help on section D. Not understanding what values to substitute into the difference quotient. I know the formula, i just don't understand what vaules to input. 
[image: allpics]
[image: GRAPH]

Comment: Involves rate of change, slope of secant lines, instantaneous rates of change, velocity functions, position functions, derivatives.Please help, again not looking for the easy way out but even an example with different data so i have something to look at and understand to answer mine.

Comment: Hint : Drawing the graph is a way to get some idea how the function acts, but much more precise is the calculation. Do you know the formula for quadratic equations ($ax^2+bx+c=0$) ? The highest point in this example is indeed at $x=3$ (value $150$), but the points where the $x-axis$ is crossed are $-0.06186$ and $6.06186$

Comment: As you see, the value $6.06$ is very good.

Comment: What did you try at part B ? What is described here is the concept of the derivation (important in physics as the momentary velocity). You start with a secant line (as described) and then the second point approaches to the first one. The slope then approaches to the derivation at the point $x=0$. In this case, it approaches $96$.

Comment: The derivation, by the way, is $-32t+96$, so the momentary velocities at the times $t=0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ are $96,64,32,0,-32,-64,-96$. As you can see, $0$ is the value at the highest point (at $x=3$).

Comment: Was all this helpful ?

Comment: In the table, you have to calculate the values of the given function $-16t^2+96t+6$. With $\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$ you can calculate the slope of a line goint through the points $(x_1,f(x_1))$ and $(x_2,f(x_2))$

Comment: This slope if the average rate of change. It approaches to the momentary rate of change, if the second point apporaches the first, as I already mentioned.

Comment: my question now is, i have these two values in the table. The first column is T and the second column is f(t)? so plugging those points in for when t= whatever value in the column for both t and f(t) and using those points to solve for slope? In that care for t=0 and t=2, I have the points t=(0,6) f(t)=(2,134) which gives me 134-6/2-0=64 feet/sec. would i then fill in 64ft./sec in the third column as the answer?

Comment: That is exactly what you have to do.

Comment: I was just wondering if anyone knew the last part E. I'm confused on the difference between slope, and the difference quotient. Are they the same thing?

Comment: The difference quotient is the slope of the line between two different points, so yes, it is the same in this sense. Note that the slope of a line is independent of the choice of the points. This is no longer true for arbitary functions such as a parabel. Here, we get the slope by approaching a second point to the given one and repeatedly calculate the slope of the line between these two points.

Comment: The edit made the text quite small. Please repeat PART E or reedit the question.